# How to create a decorator in flask?

Tags: python, flask

what can I do to replace if and else. I will need this condition in several places.

```
@blueblue.route('/', methods=['GET', 'Post'])
# 
def deactivate_trainer():
    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.account_type == 'su':

        form = ActivateDeactivateTrainer
        return render_template('x.html', form=form)
    
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('blueblue.login'))
```

Comment: Please rephrase better your question, what are you trying to do and what do you want to achieve?   Also the title mis match what you are asking,What do you want to do a decorator? Where to put the If else statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To authenticate the user while login, you could do something like this:

```
from flask import redirect, render_template, request, session
from functools import wraps

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if not (current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.account_type == 'su'):
            return redirect(url_for('blueblue.login'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

This defines a separate decorator for logging in users.
Using the decorator is as simple as including a simple line:

```
@blueblue.route('/', methods=['GET', 'Post'])
@login_required
def deactivate_trainer():
    form = ActivateDeactivateTrainer
    return render_template('x.html', form=form)
```

And voila! You don't have to use those annoying if-else conditions ever again!

Visit [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `functools.wraps()` to handle this in flask 
This is how i edited your code:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import redirect, url_for
def my_decorator(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.account_type == 'su':
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('blueblue.login'))
```

and you can use your decorator this way

```
@blueblue.route('/', methods=['GET', 'Post'])
@my_decorator
def deactivate_trainer():
    #...
```

also you can see [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/) for more information